# Increasing all product prices by percentage | Custom Script

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, magento-1, programmatically

I am trying to find a way to update all product prices by 5% then I want to revert them to the original price and wondered if anyone had any ideas of the best way to achieve this.

At the moment I am trying this:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $oldPrice = $product->getPrice();
    $increase = 1.05;
    $newPrice = round($oldPrice * $increase , 1);

    $product->setPrice($newPrice);
    $product->save();
}
```

I got this from an old post regarding Magento 1.4 but it doesn't work.

As I wanted to revert to the original price is there a better way or can someone let me know whats wrong with this code.

I have the script in a folder in ROOT.

Thanks.

Comment: The script looks fine. How do you call it ?

Comment: From the browser. I have other scripts in there that run fine from the browser.

Comment: Alright and what is the name of your script folder ?

Comment: I can access the script but it says domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: Messaged you on your answer

Comment: This works great but not for configurable products.

Answer (score 2):

As I am using PHP 7 the only way I could achieve this was an SQL Query which was a lot faster than Magento.

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->query("
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal val
SET  val.value = (val.value * 1.05)
WHERE  val.attribute_id = (
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4
AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
)
");
```

I also found an excellent extension on [Github](https://github.com/patrickbaber/Psquared_PriceFactor) which did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the following line will not work as your script is located in a subfolder:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
```

To fix that I suggest you try replacing it by:

```
require '../app/Mage.php';
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that made sense. I tried and it still didn't work. I have found out the problem is that I am using PHP 7.0.8. do you know how to get it to work with this as I can only test with PHP5

Comment: @MikeTimTurner You need to install the following module to be able to use Magento 1.x with PHP7: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: PHP is working Fine and I do already have that module installed

Comment: @MikeTimTurner and whats the error you're getting when calling the new script ? Aka how do you know the problem is related to PHP7 ?

Comment: Because I have changed the Dev site to PHP5 and it works fine

Comment: it says domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: @MikeTimTurner well that's a 500 error message. Check your server error log and post the error message ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in `updatePrice.php` and this file put on magento root folder.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class ITEMS
{
    public function index()    
    {
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $oldPrice = $product->getPrice();
            $increase = 1.05;
            $newPrice = round($oldPrice * $increase , 1);

            $product->setPrice($newPrice);
            $product->setId($product->getID());
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}

$obj = new ITEMS();
$obj->index();
?>
```

after run url eg. http://your-domainname.com/updatePrice.php in browser